# JQuery find and closest Can't find closest input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I loop through some data dynamically via Ajax and than display them in table. As you see I have multiple row or `<tr>` , *HeaderLine* and *Customerinfo*. which I'm interesting in is `CustomerInfo` and the thing I'm trying do is when button is clicked, check which input fields is Empty or has no value than give an alert  and for finding input fields or elements I used jQuery `find()` and `closest()` Method, but for some reason it can't find any elements.

Can anyone please help me to solve the issue?

**JavaScript for checking Empty input fields before sending to server:**

```
<script>
    function AnmodomRMA(e) {

        var tr = $(e).closest("table").find(".CustomerInfo");
        var email = tr.find('input.Email').val();
        var telefon = tr.find('input.Telefonnummer').val();

        if (email === "") {
            alert("Input is Empty:" + email);
            return false;
        }
        if (telefon === "") {
            alert("Input is Empty:" + telefon);
            return false;
        }

        var formdata = $("select, textarea,input").serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
            "url": '@Url.Action("AutoRMAAnmoding", "User")',
            "method": "POST",
            "data": formdata,
            "dataType": "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },

            error: function () {
                console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
            }

        });
    }
</script>
```

**JavaScript for Load Data (dynamically into table)**:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody id="ResultProduct"></tbody>

    </table>
        <div id="AppendBtnRMA">

        </div>

</div>

<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/User/serializeItemLineByID" + 1,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {

            $.each(result.findclosedorders, function (ii, e) {
                var guid = uuidv4();

                rows += '<tr class="HeaderLine">';
                rows += '<td>some data</td>';
                rows += '</tr>';

                rows += '<tr class="CustomerInfo">'
                rows += '<input type="hidden" name="model.InsertRMALists.Index" value="' + guid + '" />';
                rows += '<td><label>Telefonnummer</label><input name="model.InsertRMALists[' + guid + '].Telefonnummer" id="Telefonnummer" type="tel"></td>';
                rows += '<td><label>E-mail</label><input name="model.InsertRMALists[' + guid + '].Email" id="Email" type="text"></td>';
                rows += '</tr>';

            });
            var btnAppend = "";
            btnAppend += '<button onclick="AnmodomRMA(this);">Create RMA</button>';

            $("#AppendBtnRMA").append(btnAppend);
            $("#ResultProduct").append(rows);
        },
    })
</script>
```

Comment: From what I can see `$(e).closest("tr")` this would assume that the button you click is inside a `tr` but  when you use `$("#AppendBtnRMA").append(btnAppend);` you append it to `<div id="AppendBtnRMA">` and that is not inside a table.

Comment: Also you are gonna have a big problem `find('input#Telefonnummer')` would find the first input with the id `Telefonnummer` but you have multiple elements with that id

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i dont want loop button for each row , dat why i keep it out of $.each

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yes i know dat, id is unique and than i tried to use name but name of input fields is like : name="model.InsertRMALists[b6c29bac-ba37-4ae1-91ca-2a15f4b3e7db].Email and when i want select input with name i tried like this : .find('input[name=Email]').val() but its not going to select the element

Comment: Ok, then. What closest `tr` you need to select? I just noticed that the button is outside the table, there might be a solution in HTML reordering

Comment: @TheProfessorandtheMadman Then change `id="Telefonnummer` to `class="Telefonnummer`

Comment: @WebMarie dat tr which is contains class CustomerInfo i want to select.

Comment: I'm out of here... there's only so many times I can read "dat" and not want to scream.  As stated, you have more than one element with the same `id` which is invalid. And as also stated, you can only use `.closest` within the tree, so it can't work when the button is outside of that tree. Good luck

Comment: Try `$(e).closest("table").find("tr.CustomerInfo");`

Comment: @WebMarie that would not work, since the button is not inside the table.

Comment: What about `$(e).prev("table").find("tr.CustomerInfo");` ?

Comment: @WebMarie Do you guess or look at the html? The op would need `$(e).closest(".card-body").find("tr.CustomerInfo")`

Comment: @WebMarie i tried this one $(e).closest("table").find("tr.CustomerInfo"); its only find empty row in first tr not the others

Comment: @freefaller Maybe you come back One day :D i move the button into table :D

Comment: @TheProfessorandtheMadman a `button` as a direct child of `table` is not valid `html` I've removed my answer and leaving since there is way to many problems with this question.

Comment: Sorry, make it `$(e).closest("table").find("tr.CustomerInfo:last-child");`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i thought it could be help , and the reseon it find the first tr and not the others, its beacuse its a list tr and should loop through them and than find empty input fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all help :)

Here is how did i solve the problems:
- Add a class to input fields.
- beacuse button it was out side the table, i have to select closest element around table and than find `<tr>` like:

```
 var tr = $(e).closest(".card-body").find("tr.section");
```

and than loop through that element i want to check if it is Empty:

```
$(tr).each(function (i, el) {
            var t = $(el).find('input.Telefonnummer').val();
            if (t ==="") {
                alert("empty");

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function `AnmodomRMA(e)` e refers to the event itself and not the clicked button, try to use `e.target`:

```
      var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr");
```

Comment: While I agree with your point that e is a bad name for the variable, in the OP's case, running the code, `e` is not the problem because it does in fact return the button that is clicked.

Comment: I'm not sure about that... the call to `AnmodomRMA` is directly in the `onclick` of the element and passes `this` as the parameter... `<button type="button" onclick="AnmodomRMA(this);">`. That would mean that `e` is the button, not an event

Comment: @freefaller is right , e is not event is just parameter used for this.